# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Error

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Hi I have a problem with app:mergeDebugResources I added multidlex and check the link in Gradle.properties
jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. But id doesn't help still the same. In the logs saying that's a cooler problem. I don't have any idea what should I do. Invalid caches and Restart also didn't help
Thanks for any help

[Error  log.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLuuD.png)

Comment: File => Invalidate caches & restart

Answer (score 0):

Change -Dfile.endcoding=UTF-8  To -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).